# Array returns only last variable

Tags: php, arrays

I am a newbe so maybe stupid question..
I have a couple of variables:

```
$opleidingscode1            = rgar( $entry, '31'); //$Opleidingssoortcode
$opleidingscode2            = rgar( $entry, '32'); //$Opleidingssoortcode
$opleidingscode3            = rgar( $entry, '33'); //$Opleidingssoortcode
$opleidingscode4            = rgar( $entry, '34'); //$Opleidingssoortcode
$opleidingscode5            = rgar( $entry, '35'); //$Opleidingssoortcode
```

Then put them in an array:

```
 $array = array( $opleidingscode1,$opleidingscode2,$opleidingscode3,$opleidingscode4,$opleidingscode5 );
```

Because only one variable has a value, rest is empty, i want to return only the value. So now i have:

```
$arrlength = count($array);

$string = "";
for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
$string = $array[$x];
break; }
```

But it only returns a value if the last variable of the array has a value ($opleidingscode5)

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing here is a for-loop, that loops on each value of your array (you got that right), but it stores the last value of your table to your $string variable because that's what you asked it to do.

You may want to add a condition to your `$string = $array[$x];` statement in order to check if its empty or not, since you said "Because only one variable has a value, rest is empty, i want to return only the value."

Answer (score 1):

You're not checking if there's a value in the string, you're just getting each value and returning the last one. You need an if statement in your loop.

```
for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
    if($array[$x] != NULL){
        $string = $array[$x];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do - first filter for `empty` and then shift first item from the returned result:

```
$array = array_filter($array, function($value) {
    return !empty($value);
});

$value = array_shift($array);
```

That is if you only want the first item's value - otherwise you will already have all items that have values associated in the `$array` after running it via `array_filter`.